# Codeigniter load view with data after button submit

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a table of each request filed by the user with corresponding actions to it. When I click on the update button, it doesnt load the view after submitting it.

This is my html code:

```
<table id="dataTableRequestDrafts" class="table table-striped table-bordered data-table-drafts" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display: none;">Request ID</th>
            <th>Request Type</th>
            <th>Date Requested</th>
            <th>Date Last Updated</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($param_drafts as  $drafts){?>
        <tr>
            <td class="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo $drafts['idx']?></td>
            <td class="type"><?php echo $drafts['request_type']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $drafts['date_requested']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $drafts['date_updated']?></td>
            <td class="text-warning"><?php echo $drafts['status']?></td>
            <td align="center">
                <form action="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/request/update_request_view'); ?>" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="request_id" value="<?php echo $drafts['idx']?>" style="display: none;">
                <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-primary view-button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</button> <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info update-button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Update</button> <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-danger delete-button" data-url="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/request/delete');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my function in the controller:

```
public function update_request_view()
{   
    $data = new stdClass;
    $data->param_menu = 'request';
    $idx = $this->input->post('request_id');
    $type = $this->staffrequisition_model->getRequestType($idx);
    $typeLower = strtolower($string = str_replace(' ', '', $type));
    $commonContents = $this->staffrequisition_model->selectItem(array('idx'=> $idx));
    $uncommonContents = json_decode($commonContents->contents);
    $data->param_request = array_merge((array) $commonContents, (array) $uncommonContents);

    $this->load->view('dashboard/staff/update_'.$typeLower.'_view', $data);
}
```

The view is seen in the response but it doesnt load the view. I was gonna use ajax but it would be tedious to load the data of the request in each input in the view and I want to return the whole html page not just a div.

Comment: how "The view is seen in the response but it doesnt load the view."???

Comment: ^ exactly. confused me too. also... if you just want to load the whole page again that is NOT a task for ajax. you might as well refresh the page as there is nothing really dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the response here.
sometimes the response can't handle by browser. so it can't appear

Comment: The response is the whole html page of the view.

Comment: To the downvoter: if you are under a certain rep you *cant* comment. Give the guy a break - evened the score.